# Why Eclipse (Neon) won't start in Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, virtualbox, eclipse-neon

[Error message when starting Eclipse in Linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJw7S.png)

When I'm trying opening the eclipse (Neon) in Linux via VirtualBox, I'm getting the above error. Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Edited:
Attached the [Log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b21Gm.png)

Comment: Well, for a start Eclipse Neon (4.6) is now 5 years and 12 releases old. If you are using Java 9 or later it won't work because it is too old. What does it say in the .log file the message told you to look at?

Comment: It has no log file there. This version of the eclipse is what my project requires, so I don't have choice. @gre

Comment: The .log file is there but since the name starts with a '.' it is hidden, you need to turn on viewing hidden files. Why does the project require Neon? Newer versions of Eclipse can generally be used with older projects.

Comment: Ohh I get it. Though I already have the log file I don't understand what it pertains. See the attached file above @greg-449. Do you know what it means?

Comment: The log file shows you are trying to run with Java 14. Eclipse Neon will not run with anything after Java 8. So you either have to use a newer Eclipse or go back to Java 8.

Comment: Okay. I get it @greg-449. I'll try to lower the Java version with Java 8 so Eclipse Neon will allow it.